# "sliding window"/partition over elements

Tags: r, vector

Given the sequence `1 2 3 4`, I would like to generate a matrix of pairs

```
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

to use as indexes for another matrix. What would be the fastest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `embed()`, reversing the columns on the output.

```
embed(1:4, 2)[, 2:1]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    2
# [2,]    2    3
# [3,]    3    4
```